# Unable to share text on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an EditText and a submit button in my Android app. When I write something in my EditText and then click the submit button, it opens the Facebook dialog, but the text from the EditText is not show in the dialog.

```
    String textToShare = txt.getText().toString();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Comment: Prefilling text is against Facebook Platform Policy. That is why it doesn't work

Comment: @WizKid is there any official document or link on which it is written that we can not share text on Facebook using Facebook SDK on Android ? if yes then please share link.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill